# Pass function to alertify.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, alertify

Im knocking my head to this scripts and I cant get my function to be displayed inside the Aletify.js alerts.

Some help will be incredibly helpful ;-)

The Function:

```
        Oshoplang = { 
        // System Message Text
            RemoveError:        '<p>This item has now been removed from your cart.\n\nThank you.', 
            Added:              'Has now been added to your cart',
            OutOfStock:         '<p>This item is not currently available or is out of stock.</p>',
            PreOrder:           '<p>Your pre-order has been made successfully.\n\nThank you.</p>',
            InvalidQuantity:    '<p>It looks like you entered an invalid quantity.\n\nPlease try again.</p>',

        }

window.alert = function() {};

$("#confirm-else").on('click', function() {
                reset();
                $('#e-content').addClass('blur');
                alertify.alert(Oshoplang, function(e) {
                    if (e) {
                        alertify.success("OK");
                        $('#e-content').removeClass('blur');
                                                                                                            location.reload();
                    } else {
                        alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

I normally don't get a message on the run, but this way but i believe i'm close somewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having this issue, but I believe that the `alertify.alert` function doesn't have any callbacks, as it's just a way to show a message. You're probably looking for the `alertify.confirm` instead.

The message is also not showing up because the first argument to `alertify.alert` or `alertify.confirm` needs to be a string. In your example, you're passing an object.

I've set up a demo of your code which has been adjusted to work on [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2enwkr1/).

For what it's worth, the code sample is using an older version of alertify (0.3) and it has been updated, so that version 1 [which is now out](https://alertifyjs.org) would have a somewhat adjusted syntax.